# First empty character in BufferedReader on Android

Tags: java, php, android, string, bufferedreader

I have a problem with my APP Android. My aplicaction es very simple. It is Login screen for authentication.

My problem is, that when reading the data with the BufferedReader, I think it does not read correctly. Because the first value of the String is always empty.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(line);
}
is.close();
String vIdEmpleado = sb.toString();
```

The value that returns my PHP file is: idEmployee (if exists) and "0" (if not exists). But the value that returns me, always contains this character in the first position ('\uFEFF').

[image]

Then when I do the idEmployee.equals("0")... Does it incorrectly.

```
if (vIdEmpleado.equals("0"))
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

I have chosen to use idEmployee.substring(1), but I do not think it is the most correct way to program.

I use:

- Login Screen with Android (Java).
- WebService: I use XAMPP in localhost.
- Reader in my date base: PHP
- Database: MySQL

Anyone have any ideas?

If you need me to write my code... it will not be a problem

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try to trim function remove space**

```
String vIdEmpleado = sb.toString.trim();
```

**Then try this one**

```
if (vIdEmpleado.contains("0"))
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: It's very weird. Since I evaluate the expression and it returns true, but it does not enter the IF.

But this would be a solution similar to SUBSTRING. And I would like to know why this happens

Thank's!